# Insert text in cells when above cell meets condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a schedule sheet for the whole year for a group.
The third row has all the dates of the year, the next couple of rows has the name of each group member.

Members specified in A4:A9.
Holidays are specified in cells A20:A28.

So, what I want to do, probably through VBA, is to make a rule like with conditional formatting, that inserts the word "Holiday" in B4:B9 if B3 matches a date in A$20:A$28, and then into C4:C9 if C3 matches and so on.

Now I cannot write this condition in every cell since it's a schedule used by every member, which is the suggestion I often got from googling, and I can't do it with conditional formatting, so I'm guessing VBA is the way to go, but the VBA code I've found so far seems to use specific cells and wouldn't go through each column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). You might also want to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour "Magical Mystery Tour") and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the `VBA` code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Even recording a macro is a way to start.

Comment: All you need to solve your problem is to use 'for each' and 'if...then...else' statements. You can read about them in VBA help (in Excel press Alt+F11, then F1).

Comment: @EganWolf I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: What @EganWolf said, combined with a simple Offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without questioning your general approach, a simple code that does what you plan to do could work like the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub markhd()

    ' get calendardays, holidays and employees somehow into collections
    ' that can be looped. Since that information is stored in a worksheet,
    ' using ranges is one way to achive that

    ' holidays
    Dim rhd As Range
    Set rhd = ActiveSheet.Range("A20:A28")

    ' group employees
    Dim remp As Range
    Set remp = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:A9")

    ' calendar days
    Dim rcal As Range
    Set rcal = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:NB3")

    Dim c As Object

    ' Loop every day (every c-object in your calendar days), 
    ' then write "Holiday", if it matches an entry in your holiday-range
    For Each c In rcal
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(c, rhd.Cells, False)) Then
            remp.Offset(0, c.Column - remp.Column).Value = "Holiday"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Note:

- The concept @EganWolf mentioned is to look for similar objects (calendar days in this example) and iterate through them, performing an action (writing "Holiday") if a check is passed (calendarday is in the range of holidays). There is a gazillion of different ways implement this, i merely posted one easy to follow example
- Looping each and every calendar day we're doing 365 iterations here, attempting to match each calendarday in the 9 holidays.
- However, we could do this the other way around: loop the 9 holidays, match them in the 365 calendar days, therefore looping only 9 times. Performance could theoretically swing both ways, since despite having less iterations, a single iteration could take longer... but, obviously, at 365 days performance is merely a theoretical problem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Performance isn't an issue, it's just something to prevent too much manual typing.